# Extend HashMap putChildren method

Tags: java, javascript, hashmap

***I'm very new on Java. I'd appreciate it if your answers considering this situation.***

I have question, I want to develop a programme about extend the hashmap to add putchildren method. I wrote something.

***My question is :***

The task is extending the HashMap to include HashMaps as an object. so, this inner hashMap can also have key value pairs. It will be like tree with depth 2 . When you finish the method data

```
Key1 = "RUBY" value=HashMap which has -> "key2" = 5248 && "VALUE" = German
Key1 = "PYTHON" value=HashMap which has -> "key2" = 1234 && -> "VALUE" = German
```

you will implement a putChildrenValue method with 3 parameters, String key, String key, Object
Value. It will store the system as described above accordingly.

***My code is:***

```
     public class ExtHashMap<K1, K2, V> extends HashMap<K1, HashMap<K2, V>>
     {     
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public ExtHashMap() {       
           super();   
        }

        public void putChildrenValue(K1 key1, K2 key2, V value) { 
            HashMap<K2, V> childMap = get(key2);
            if (childMap == null) { 
             childMap = new HashMap<K2, V>();
             put(key1, childMap);
            }
            childMap.put(key2, value);
         }    
      }
```

***And I run the code, after select Run as Java Application, Eclipse say= "Selection does not contain a main type"***

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with your code. What exactly you are expecting ?

Comment: I run the code, after select Run as Java Application, Eclipse say= "Selection does not contain a main type"

Comment: What do you expect to run?

Comment: It is my project. And the question is this:

The task is extending the HashMap to include HashMaps as an object. so, this inner HashMap can also have key value pairs. It will be like tree with depth 2 . When you finish the method data

' **Key1 = "RUBY" value=HashMap which has -> "key2" = 5248 && "VALUE" = German
Key1 = "PYTHON" value=HashMap which has -> "key2" = 1234 && -> "VALUE" = German** '

you will implement a putChildrenValue method with 3 parameters, String key, String key, Object Value. It will store the system as described above accordingly

Comment: Expect I nothing to run? I don't know this :(

Answer (score 1):

Your statement

```
    HashMap childMap = get(key2);
```

should be

```
    HashMap childMap = get(key1);
```

As you are trying to load the main map.